# Discord bot modal not saving i get Failed to send registration form

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

below is the code i am currently using and the User (userSchema is being imported from index)

Now i get this error on log
Submitted Data: { components: undefined, fields: undefined }

apparantly the data is not being saved and fields too i dont know why

here is the code
https://srcshare.io/65f43568c18a10143f3a8df2

in index.js i have this

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  discordId: { type: String, unique: true },
  username: String,
  team: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Team" },
  idCardNumber: String,
  phoneNumber: String,
  name: String,
  platform: String,
  platformId: String,
});
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

// Define schema and model for storing teams
const teamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true },
  members: [{ discordId: String, username: String }],
});
const Team = mongoose.model("Team", teamSchema);

// Set up Discord client
const token = process.env.DISCORD_BOT_SECRET;
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const GUILD_ID = process.env.GUILD_ID;

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
});
const rest = new REST({ version: "10" }).setToken(token);

client.on("ready", () => console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in!`));
client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  const { commandName, options } = interaction;

  if (commandName === "register") {
    await handleRegister(interaction, User, client.guilds);
  } else if (commandName === "team") {
    await handleTeam(interaction, User, Team);
  }
});
```

please let me know how to fix this and these datas are being saved to monogoDB

im using
"@discordjs/rest": "^2.2.0",
"@types/node": "^18.0.6",
"discord.js": "^14.14.1",

Comment: _"i get Failed to send registration form"_ - please clarify, are you saying that you are getting the `Registration failed.` error message from the `catch` block? If so, what did the `error` you logged to console have to say?

Comment: i get Failed to send registration form on discord bot and try catch block it doesnt give an error thats the problem